# Why is $\left|\int_0^{R_1} \frac{e^{-xR_2}\sin x}{x}dx \right| \leqslant \int_0^{R_1} e^{-xR_2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $R_1 \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $R_2 \in \mathbb{R^+\cup\{0\}}$

Since $|\sin x/x|<1$ for $x>0$,

why,
$$\displaystyle\left|\int_0^{R_1} \frac{e^{-xR_2}\sin x}{x}dx \right| \leqslant \int_0^{R_1} e^{-xR_2}dx$$

I think, $$\displaystyle\left|\int_0^{R_1} \frac{e^{-xR_2}\sin x}{x}dx \right| < \int_0^{R_1} e^{-xR_2}dx$$

Someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: If $A<B$, then $A\leq B$. What is the problem? There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

$$f(r)\leq g(r),\text{ for all $r\in X$}$$
does not mean that they necessarily are equal for some $r$. It is just the statement that for all $r\in X$ either $f(r)<g(r)$ or $f(r)=g(r)$.

So there is no contradiction in your question.

Quite often in an inequality, if we only need $\leq$ for a later argument, we stick with $\leq$ at every step, even when we can show $<$.